# django how to rename PK field in a url

Tags: django, django-views

if anyone can help me  with how to rename  pk for a class(table) when I use it in the urlpattern.
(my goal is using many classes(tables ) PK in the same url and I want to know how to rename PK field for each table)
My code below is just for one class(table) for simplicity:

models.py:

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("basic_app:school_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

views.py:

```
class SchoolListView(ListView):
    model = models.School


class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'school_details'
    model = models.School
    template_name = 'basic_app/school_detail.html'
```

and my current urls.py (which I want to edit) :

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name='school_list'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name='school_detail'),]
```

So my goal is to make the urls.py file look like this(school_pk instead of pk):

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name='school_list'),
url(r'^(?P<school_pk>\d+)/$',views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name='school_detail'),]
```

I know I should add a function below class SchoolDetailView in views.py but I don’t know how ?
I am still learning so any help will be highly appreciated..Thanks in Advance

Comment: You mean changing the **value** of `pk` of some instance?

Comment: I mean renaming pk value in the url so instead of pk I use some other name. I need this becuse later I will need to have multiple PK in same url(each Pk for different class(table). like for example a student in a specific school... the url will be something like :  url(r'^school/(?P<school_pk>\d+)/student/(?P<student_pk>\d+)/$',views.StudentDetailView.as_view(),name='student_detail'),    .....in this case if I leave PK without renaming it.. django will not understand which PK I am referring to (school table PK or Student table PK).

Answer (score 0):

When declaring your model you can make a field primary by including `primary_key=True`, eg

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
```

You can then use `name` within your URL.

I would recommend using unique slug fields.

**EDIT**

The URL isn't interested if it is called pk or slug or name.  It is interested in the pattern. If you have a URL patterns

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\\-]+)/$', views.Type1View.as_view(), name="slug"),
url(r'^(?P<city>[\w\\-]+)/$', views.Type2View.as_view(), name="city"),
```

Both {% url 'slug' slug %} and {% url 'city' slug %} will produce a URL or `/slug/` and both will call Type1View.as_view()

You need to ensure your URLs are unique.

If you want to refer to 3 tables then your url pattern is

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\\-]+)/(?P<slug1>[\w\\-]+)/(?P<slug2>[\w\\-]+)/$', MyView.as_view(), name="someName"),
```

And then within your view define def `get_objects(self)` or `def get_queryset(self)` to pick up the info you want.

Comment: ...I already tried this....this also gave me an error...Generic detail view SchoolDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug

Comment: Yes, so use a slug as your primary key

Comment: @ HenryM but what if need to refer to 3 tables? I will use pk for one ,slug for the second ..what will I use for the third? ..like if I have school---student--- subject grade...I am sure there is a way to rename pk or slug otherwise it is impossible to deal with relational database in real world.